# String to double conversion with 2 decimal places

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am using following code to format a double value.
For example, if input is *34*, output double value should be *34.00*.

```
Double value = new Double(34);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat =new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.applyPattern("#.00");
System.out.println("String format " + decimalFormat.format(value));
double formattedValue =Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(value));
System.out.println("double format " + formattedValue);
```

Here output:

> String format 34.00
>   double format 34.0

I don't want to use `BigDecimal`.

Here our final requirement is to store  formatted value in a double type field.

Comment: A `double` value doesn't have a "format".

Comment: You are storing your value numerically. `double` does not preserve significant figures, so no matter how many figures you have in your string, you will still get 34.0 when you print it out. You will have to re-format the double when you print it.

Comment: Don't assign it to *formattedValue*. Print the *decimalFormat.format(value)* itself (as shown by @Reimeus)

Comment: Hey thanks. Here requirement is to store formatted value in a double field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `double` can be formatted to "any" kind of `String` as you see in your first example, but a `double` doesn't have a format internally (at least one that you could modify). That's why you can't make your second line print `34.00` no matter what you do, without converting it to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I mean, there's always good old printf...

```
System.out.printf("value is %.0f\n", value);
```

Or likewise:

```
String formatted = String.format("%.0f", value);
```

Reiterating the other comments: A double is a double. It doesn't have an inherent display format. Formatting it is a function of how you display it.